# How to hide element if ng-content dont exists in Angular?

Tags: angular

How to hide element if ng-content not exists in Angular?

```js
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-header #title *ngIf="title"> <-- title
        <mat-card-title>
            <ng-content select="[title]"></ng-content>
        </mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-divider *ngIf="title"></mat-divider>
    <mat-card-content>
        <ng-content select="[content]"></ng-content>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

if **ng-container title** not exists, then hiding **mat-card-heade**r in the component above

```js
<card>
  <ng-container title>
    title
   </ng-container>
   <ng-container content>
    ....
   </ng-container>
</card>
```

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'card',
    templateUrl: './card.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./card.component.scss']
})
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('title', {static: true}) titleRef: ElementRef;
    
    title = true;
    // contentExists = true;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    if ((this.titleRef.nativeElement.innerHTML ?? '').trim() === '') {
            this.title = false;
    }
```

TS logic

Comment: Can you also share the typescript file? So we can see what causes the logic no to work?

Comment: yeah, sure, I'm updated the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be moved to `NgAfterViewInit` cycle as element ref's can be access at the earliest in the cycle.

```js
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if ((this.titleRef.nativeElement.innerHTML ?? '').trim() === '') {
            this.title = false;
    }
```

I don't see the whole context in you example but I wouldn't add unnecessary TS code (the `@ViewChild`) just to get one boolean. This could all be done in template.

Also, keep in mind, that template is being rendered from highest layer to lowest.

Now if we change in the template a parent element based on some child layer result (e.g `ng-content` the child result will remove `mat-card` the parent) then we will start getting `Expression has changed` errors, because template itself changed. `mat-card` got removed before the whole rendering cycle finished. Make sure to start rendering stuff from parent -> child, not going backwards at any point.

1. First find if `mat-card` it worth being rendered at all?
2. Then if the `title` should be rendered.
3. Then if the `content` should be rendered and so on...

```html
<mat-card *ngIf="item">

  <ng-container *ngIf="title">
    <mat-card-header #title>
      <mat-card-title>
        <ng-content select="[title]"></ng-content>
      </mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-card-content *ngIf="content">
    <ng-content select="[content]"></ng-content>
  </mat-card-content>
  
</mat-card>
```